# Grungit add on isn't showing up in Blender side bar

Tags: add-on

I just purchased Grungit, and installed it, but it isn't showing up in my sidebar. It shows up in preferences-I can see it and I checked the box, saved the preferences, but it never came up in the sidebar as it should. I really need this thing asap and don't know what's going on.I have contacted the artist who made it but haven't heard back yet.

Comment: Since it's a third-party paid-for addon and not built-in to Blender we can't really help. Have you checked that the version you've purchased is the correct one for the Blender version that you are using?

Comment: I fixed it. Just so all of you know and don't lose a work day like I did, this add on only shows up in object mode. All my other add ons work in either Obj or Edit modes.